# Anyone can explain to me why i cannot printf out the array value?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am starting to study C++ code, i don't understand why i cannot printf out name[j][i] value, anyone can teach and explain to me? THX~

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void array_copy(int *p, int *q){
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; *q++ = *p++, i++);
}

int main(){
  int a[10], b[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; a[i] = i + 1, i++);

  array_copy(a, b);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char name[2] = {'a', 'b'};
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      printf("%c[%d] : %d\n", name[j], i, name[j][i]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use cout, not printf.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the first two loops are very confusing. Separate the **control** in the loop from the **operation** that the loop does. The first one should be `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) *q++ = *p++;` and the second one should be `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) a[i] = i + 1;`.

Answer (score 3):

```
name[j][i]
```

Here `name` is not 2d array. You are doing it wrong.

You can do this

```
printf("%c[%d] : %d\n", name[j], i, name[j]=='a'?a[i]:b[i]);
```

Or

```
int *pp[2]={a,b};
printf("%c[%d] : %d\n", name[j], i, pp[name[j]-'a'][i]);
```

To explain the second one, we are storing the pointers pointing to the first element of the array in the array `pp`. Then we print it based on the character in `name[j]`.

when `name[j]` is `a` then we access the array `pp` at position `0` or `name[j]-'a'` and for `b` we accessat index `1`(see this is equal to `b`-`a`)<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1)
Now ascii value of `a` and `b` are continguous. So we will get correct offser from `a` - that is what is being used in indexing.</sup>

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.
OK, clear explain. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

name is not a 2d array. You can create a 2d array and add the values like this:

```
char name[2][10] = { 0 };
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        if(i == 0){
            name[i][a] = a[i];
        }
        else{
            name[i][a] = b[i];
        }
    }
}
```

What coderredoc said to do is a more elegant way of what you are trying to do. However if you are in a class, and have not learned the concepts he uses, your professor may not accept that as a valid answer.

sidebar: If you are in a class, there are some things to take with a grain of salt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk